# MATLAB extract data from mat-files using logical conditions

Tags: database, matlab, matlab-table

I have a lot of data in several hundred .mat-files where I want to extract specific data from. All the names of my .mat-files have specific numbers to identify the content like Number1_Number2_Number3_Number4.mat:

```
01_33_06_121.mat
01_24_12_124.mat
02_45_15_118.mat
02_33_11_190.mat
01_33_34_142.mat
```

Now I want to extract for example all the data from files with Number1=01 or Number1=02 and Number2=33.

Before I start to write a program from scratch, I would like to know, if there is a simple way to do this with Matlab. Does anybody know how I can solve this problem in a fast way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this; on top of my head following can work:

1. Obtain all the file names into an array

   allFiles = dir( 'folder' );

   allNames = { allFiles.name };
2. Loop through your file names and compare against the condition using the [regex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html)

   for i=1:size(allNames)

   ```
   if regexp(allNames, pattern, 'match')
       disp(allNames)
   end
   ```

   end